# Entity Framework Code First: good way to convert legacy business objects to EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have been given responsibility of a VB6 app with a .NET component.

The previous programmer, for reasons unclear, thought it would be a good idea to write out business objects in .NET that represent virtually all of the important data in the app.  They match quite well to the existing database tables and structure.

Would using EF's Code First on these objects be a good way to create a new EF model if I am rewriting the app in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Code first works quite well with existing data models. The fluent mappings are pretty intuitive.

I've been transitioning a big application to EF4.1 over the last couple of months and haven't run into any real difficulties.

In short, I like it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you can use the code first approach with the existing business objects or you can use a database first approach and generate your model based on the database, for [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489).

If you business objects closely match your database then might be faster to use the database first approach.

Comment: I thought the whole point of ER was that you're not directly dealing with databases anymore.

Comment: The db first approach generates a model based on your db.  The model contains the entity classes that you then utilise.  Code first you create these classes and if they match your db everything will be fine but you may have to do some work to setup navigation Properties etc.